# Too many requests error when implemented load balancer in Laravel webapp

Tags: php, laravel, server, load-balancing

Last weekend we have added a load-balancer for our api since the server is constantly very busy.

Currently the load balancer balances between 2 servers. On these 2 servers we have the throttle functionality to limit hourly requests. These are stored on a database server outside of the 2 api servers.

On login to my web app it says too many requests, I can't see any fix for this and also does not know what is causing this. Is there somebody here that has experience with this?

Any tip is welcome!

Thanks too

Answer (score 0):

What cloud provider that you use? I don't know if this will answer your question. But Load Balancers will do request frequently (maybe every 5 seconds) to your active instances. What this for? It's for health check. It check for availability, that when an instance going busy It will forward the request to another instance. I'm not sure how your throttle works, and why that you doing it. But I hope this give you some hints.